# Does verifying the mock is need in minitest

Tags: minitest

I'm reading the mocking capability of minitest.

```
require "minitest/autorun"

mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
mock.expect(:use_any_string, true, [String])
mock.use_any_string("foo")
## mock.use_any_string(1)
## MockExpectationError: mocked method :use_any_string called with unexpected arguments [1]


## I do not understand the purpose for this 
mock.verify
```

So I do not understand the purpose of using `mock.verify` since the trying to pass any another type(to `use_any_string`) other than String result in mock expectation error.

So why should one use `assert mock.verify` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you cannot set anything else to the configured mock, but if your mock is not called at all, then you can find out with `mock.verify`. So if your method under test should call the mocked method, you should verify that it was called at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `mock.expect(:use_any_string, true, [String])` will cause the test to fail if the expected call is not made on the mock.

However using `mock.verify` depends on how you compose your test. In your example you are explicitly calling the method you are testing with `mock.use_any_string("foo")` so there is no need to also call mock.verify.

You could get into a scenario where you are not making this call explicitly, or are expecting the mock to have had calls made at a certain time. These scenarios would take advantage of mock.verify calls.

(Another note, minitest has recently introduced assert_mock which can be used instead of mock.verify)